# how to handle php forloop returning no results

Tags: php, codeigniter, for-loop

Im running a for loop to gather data from a forum table, but im not quite sure what to do to make it handle if there are no results returned. Here is the code i have to gather the data.

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM newslist ORDER BY pubdate DESC");
if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
return $data; else {
    return echo = "nose";
}
```

Comment: I keep receiving an invalid argument in both methods that were listed below

Answer (score 1):

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM newslist ORDER BY pubdate DESC");
$data = array(); // Initialize the array in case there are no records.
if ($q->num_rows() > 0){
  foreach ($q->result() as $row){
    $data[] = $row;
  }
}
if (empty($data)) { // If there are no records, $data will be empty.
  return "nose";
}
else { // If $data has records, will return data from SQL.
  return $data;
}
```

**Explanation:**

1) Initialize the `$data` variable. If we do not get any records, `$data` will not be appended, causing initialized variable `$data` return error. By initializing it before loop, we are overcoming it.

2) Check `empty()` ness of `$data`, if its empty, return error string, else `$data`.

Comment: its returning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

Little bit of a flow issue. See revised solution.

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM newslist ORDER BY pubdate DESC");
        if($q->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($q->result() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }

            return $data;
        } //<-- this was on the wrong line
        else {
            return "No data!";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Return your data inside `if` condition and don't use `return and echo` at same time.

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM newslist ORDER BY pubdate DESC");
if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;// return data inside if condition
}
 else {
    return "nose";// remove echo from here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply You can use this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM newslist ORDER BY pubdate DESC");
$result = $query->result_array();
$count = count($result);// counting data 

if(empty($count))
{
    $log = 'nose';
    return $log;
}
else
{
    return $result;
}
```